# How to cast a specific date within a date range. (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

I want to Generate a date within a date range in mysql.

I can't explain what i really need to do so i put it this way.

```
SELECT CAST(BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('05/06/2015','%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('05/20/2015','%m/%d/%Y') AS DATE)
```

Output should be:

- 05/06/2015
- 05/07/2015
- ...
- 05/20/2015

Comment: Do you have permissions to create objects in the database (e.g. tables, stored procedures) or can you only execute select statements?

Comment: @AlexWoolford No Sir. I can only execute select statements.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have permissions to create and execute stored procedures, you could do this:

```
awoolford$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 

mysql> use test;
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE createDateRange (IN startDate DATE, IN endDate DATE)
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE currentDate DATE;
    ->     SET currentDate := startDate;
    ->     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dateRange;
    ->     CREATE TABLE dateRange(`date` date);
    ->     WHILE currentDate <= endDate DO
    ->         INSERT INTO dateRange VALUES (currentDate);
    ->         SET currentDate := DATE_ADD(currentDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    ->     END WHILE;
    -> END//
mysql> delimiter ;

mysql> CALL createDateRange('2015-04-24', '2015-05-01');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from dateRange;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2015-04-24 |
| 2015-04-25 |
| 2015-04-26 |
| 2015-04-27 |
| 2015-04-28 |
| 2015-04-29 |
| 2015-04-30 |
| 2015-05-01 |
+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But as you said this is only intended for who have permissions. So anyways thank you again.